# Irc Server/Kiwi IRC questions

Tags: debian, irc

I just installed IRC server & kiwi IRL on my debian server, everything was okay but now on the kiwi irc I have the message:

> (Closing Link: anonymous5_6434[unknown@...] (Too many host connections (local)))

Yesterday it worked... how to fix it ? I'm really novice in the domain

Other thing, my kiwi irc client is like http://mywebsite.com:7778 - it's possible to put it like http://irc.mywebsite.com : so without the port number ?

I already have a website on my server, but there is maybe a solution ? Thank you

My config:

```
# This is ircd's config-file. Look at
# /usr/share/doc/ircd-irc2/ircd.conf.example.gz and
# and /usr/share/doc/ircd-irc2/INSTALL.* for more detailled information
# and instructions

# M-Line
M:irc.outline.lol::Debian ircd default configuration::000A

# A-Line
A:This is Debian's default ircd configurations:Please edit your /etc/ircd/ircd.$

# Y-Lines
Y:1:90::100:512000:5.5:100.100
Y:2:90::300:512000:5.5:250.250

# I-Line
I:*:::0:1
I:127.0.0.1/32:::0:1
```

Answer (score 0):

"(Too many host connections (local))" is an error by your IRC server. It is saying there are too many connections from the same host (local) which is a setting in your irc config.

You can raise this setting in your IRC server, or the usual way is to configure WEBIRC/CGIIRC to pass your users hostnames correctly to IRC. The kiwiirc docs for this can be found here: https://kiwiirc.com/docs/installing/webirc

As for the port in the URL, you need to run kiwiirc on port 80 to not have it shown in the URL. This is the standard port for all websites. This can be set in the kiwiirc config.js file near the top.